# onunload Ajax not always working (Chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome extension, and I want to fire a POST submission RIGHT before my client unloads a webpage.

To do this, I tried using both window.onunload and window.beforeunload. When the page unloads, I use jQuery.ajax to make my POST submission. I also include async: false in my request.

With this, my POST triggers successfully for MOST WEBSITES upon unloading. However, there are some websites that just don't seem to be firing the unload function!

Sites that aren't triggering for me include (just out of testing): http://www.yahoo.com and http://www.paulgraham.com/ds.html

I am really stuck. Is there something specific about the sites that aren't firing that I'm not accounting for? What can I do to make my function trigger universally?

Thank you!

Comment: Dispatch a message from the content script to the background page, and let the background page perform the AJAX request.

Comment: Hm, how exactly would I do that? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey Rob, so it doesn't seem to be working... can you explain why exactly this is supposed to work as opposed to the Ajax approach that I'm using right now?

Comment: Your original method works fine for me on Yahoo (well, using VanillaJS, but using jQuery should not matter much). My method has a big advantage that it doesn't slow down casual browsing. Your method, on the other hand, blocks all navigation until the server has responded, which is a extremely good reason to uninstall your extension, regardless of what it does (wink, hint, wink). Since you didn't show any code related to your question, I can't help you further.

Comment: Hey Rob, so it still doesn't seem to be working. Is your method working for the second link I sent?

Comment: Yes. Are you using a background page or an event page?